# reactivating or binding a hover function in jquery?

Tags: jquery, binding, hover

with the following three lines:

```
$( ".thumb" ).bind( "mousedown", function() {
        $('.thumb').not(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    });
```

i'm unbinding this hover-function:

```
$(".thumb").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).not('.text, .file, .video, .audio').stop().animate({"height": full}, "fast");
        $(this).css('z-index', z);
        z++;        
      },
      function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({"height": small}, "fast");
      }
    );
```

i wonder how i can re-bind the exact same hover function again on mouseup?
the follwoing three lines arent't working!

```
$( ".thumb" ).bind( "mouseup", function() {
$('.thumb').bind('mouseenter mouseleave');
});
```

to get what i wanna do here's a small explanation. I want to kind of deactivate the hover function for ALL .thumbs-elements when i click on one. So all (but not this) should not have the hover function assigned while i'm clicking on an object. If i release the mouse again, the hover function should work again like before.

Is that even possible to do?
thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a custom function:

```
function bind_hover(elements) {   
    elements.hover(
      // ...
    );   
};
```

and later:

```
$( ".thumb" ).bind( "mouseup", function() {
    bind_hover($('.thumb').not(this));
});
```

---

This

```
$('.thumb').bind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

cannot work. You are not specifying *which* handlers you want to bind.